Which Shopware 6 class interpretes shopware rules
I am creating a custom plugin with custom fields that requires Shopware rules to work. Which Shopware 6 class processes or interpret the Shopware rules especially the 'payload' column (in the database table) which contains the logic (if, or, and, etc)? I wish to use this class as a reference for my own code.
Here is a link to the Shopware rule concept: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/framework/rules.html

Here are some useful classes for you:
Shopware\Core\Framework\Rule\RuleScope;

Shopware\Core\Framework\Rule\Rule;

Shopware\Core\Content\Rule\RuleEntity;

and more can be found under Shopware\Core\Content\Rule directory
